# How to write single SQL query to fetch multiple results from same column with different conditions

Tags: sql, subquery, pivot

```
SELECT 
(SELECT mainop 
FROM data_final2 
WHERE (id = A.id) 
AND (os = 1 and test = 2 and mainop BETWEEN 0 AND 500)) AS op1, 

(SELECT mainop 
FROM data_final2 
WHERE (id = A.id) 
AND (os = 1 and test = 2 and mainop BETWEEN 500 AND 1000)) AS op2, 

(SELECT mainop 
FROM data_final2 
WHERE (id = A.id) 
AND (os = 1 and test = 2 and mainop BETWEEN 1001 AND 1500)) AS op3 

FROM data_final2 AS A WHERE A.mainop BETWEEN 0 AND 500 OR A.mainop BETWEEN 500 AND 1000 OR A.mainop BETWEEN 1001 AND 1500
```

I want to write this query in single SQL query without using sub-queries with each outputs % from total count.

Also want to remove Null from output

```
[{"name":"op1","data":[229,null,null,268,null,3
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use subequeries?

Comment: Maybe he's getting "too many rows returned" error?

Comment: Can you show us the format you want for your new output?

Comment: What do you mean about `"want each outputs % from total count."` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` statement to display your data based on multiple conditions on the same column.

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN mainop BETWEEN 0 AND 500
            AND os = 1 AND test = 2
            THEN mainop
        ELSE NULL
    END as op1
    , CASE 
        WHEN mainop BETWEEN 501 AND 1000
            AND os = 1 AND test = 2
            THEN mainop
        ELSE NULL
    END as op2
   , CASE 
        WHEN mainop BETWEEN 1001 AND 1500
            AND os = 1 AND test = 2
            THEN mainop
        ELSE NULL
    END as op3
FROM data_final2
WHERE mainop BETWEEN 0 AND 1500
```

You can also specify multiple `CASE` statements on the same column to generate different data.

**Update:**

After re-reading your question, I think you could actually be looking for something like this:

```
SELECT 100 * count(CASE 
            WHEN mainop BETWEEN 0 AND 500
                AND os = 1 AND test = 2
                    THEN 1
                ELSE NULL
        END) * 1.0 / (SELECT count(*) FROM data_final2) AS 'op1'
    ,100 * count(CASE 
            WHEN mainop BETWEEN 501 AND 1000
                AND os = 1 AND test = 2
                    THEN 1
                ELSE NULL
        END) * 1.0 / (SELECT count(*) FROM data_final2) AS 'op2'
    ,100 * count(CASE WHEN mainop BETWEEN 1001 AND 1500
                AND os = 1 AND test = 2
                    THEN 1
                ELSE NULL
        END) * 1.0 / (SELECT count(*) FROM data_final2) AS 'op3'
FROM data_final2
WHERE mainop BETWEEN 0 AND 1500
```

If you're looking for displaying this row as a percentage number, please look at your specific RDBMS functions to convert the data to the appropriate type.

Also, here is a [SQLFiddle with what the query returns](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84defd/1).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Was just correcting my query to add the additional conditions. It's true that it might not behave the same, but for that we need more info from OP. But, there also might be the case where this query is the solution or help him realize what can be done.

Comment: its working sir,,,thank u very much...i need exact output which you provide.... thanks once again

Comment: @BharatKoshti You're welcome, don't forget to mark the answer as correct / upvote, everytime you ask a question and get a correct answer here on StackOverflow.